# Edit post data before it's sent to server in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to edit JavaScript-generated POST data in Firefox Quantum before it's sent to the server? In Inspect Element -> Network, there is an 'Edit and **Re**send' option, but I need to edit the data before it's ever sent to the server.

I've seen extensions like Tamper Data that seem to do that (I don't know for sure because I can't use them), but they don't work with Firefox Quantum.

Answer (score 0):

you could set xhr breakpoint by keyword in firefox devtool debugger，once the js trigger a request，it stop an you'll get the unsend request in network panel. then edit and resend as your need.

another way is use keyword breakpoint in charles application, and when  the js trigger a request, use edit and compose function in charles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).